# Automatic chart axes using json

Tags: json, vega-lite, vega

I'm building a graph using json, and I would like that the start and the end of the axis (x and y) to be automatically adjusted according to the data. And also I would like to set the tick intervarl (or tick frequency) of the axes. Does anyone know thow to make these adjustement in the script below?

[image]

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "point",
        "filled": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Pop Plantas",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Yield",
          "type": "quantitative"
          
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "color": "firebrick"
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "regression": "Yield",
          "on": "Pop Plantas",
          "method": "poly",
          "order": 2
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Pop Plantas",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Yield",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "regression": "Yield",
          "on": "Pop Plantas",
          "params": true
        },
        {
          "calculate": "'R²: '+format(datum.rSquared, '.2f')",
          "as": "R2"
        }
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "color": "firebrick",
        "x": "width",
        "align": "right",
        "y": -5
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "type": "nominal",
          "field": "R2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Jut add a `"scale": {"zero": false}` to the encodings for the axes you don't want to start from zero, see [this example](https://shorturl.at/kIK17)

Comment: Is this Deneb or something else? Usually the axes are calculated automatically from the domain.

Comment: Kikon thanks for your answer! It worked!

David Bacci it is Deneb.

Answer (score 0):

Kikon answered:

Just add a "scale": {"zero": false} to the encoding for the axes you don't want to start from zero.